# Prove that the segments formed by two internal segments to a circle crossing each other when multiplied are equal

Tags: geometry

This is a simple math question to which I had an answer a long time ago but that doesn't come to mind immediately right now.

Using the picture attached, how would I prove that a*b = c*d

[Illustration http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/8254/circledo.jpg](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/8254/circledo.jpg)

Comment: This is a programming website

Comment: This is the basis for a geometry program I'm in the process of building. Thank you for the great help.

Comment: If A+B = C+D then by symmetry A=C and B=D. Otherwise they are not actually the same. It may be that A*D = B*C, but I'd have to think about that one.

Comment: How exactly does having a proof apply to a geometry program?  I'm curious.  Is it a teaching tool?

Comment: The program just visually illustrates some properties of geometry shapes... it is a teaching tool.
The proof is just for self assurance of this specific property. I was given it by a faculty member who got it off a geometry book.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be what you're after:

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/IntersectingChordsTheorem.shtml

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you, it refreshed my memory now.